# How can I visualize triples in the form of a knowledge graph in a web application?

Tags: javascript, web-applications, visualization, triples

I have a text file with all the triples (from OpenIE). I want to visualize the triples in the form of a **knowledge graph** in my **web application**. I am already aware of Neo4j, but they have a seperate UI of their own to visualize the knowledge graph.
How can I use the same or are there other good **JavaScript** libraries to do the same?